# Extracting all variable names from Variable declarations using Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have been working on analyzing source code using Eclipse JDT. 
Currently, I have a program that is able to get some code, convert it to an AST and then make some annotations.

Now, what I want to do is, for each variable declaration, get all the variables involved. For example:

```
int  a = 10;
```

Its easy, just variable `a`

But in the following case :

```
int a = b +c ;
```

I need to analyze the right part and extract each variable.
What I have until now is this :

For each variable declaration:

```
//get the fragment                                   
List<VariableDeclarationFragment> ff = vds_p.fragments();

//foreach fragment, get the name of the variable and the value associated
for(VariableDeclarationFragment f_p : ff){
   SimpleName name = f_p.getName();
   Expression exp  =  f_p.getInitializer();
   ChildPropertyDescriptor exp_prop = f_p.getInitializerProperty();

   System.out.println("name: "+name);
   System.out.println("expression: "+exp);
}
```

So, Im able to get the name of the variable and the expression which is assigned to it. 
Now, here is my question:

How can I analyze using JDT the expression being assigned to the variable, For example in

```
int a = b + c ;
```

I want to get `b` and `c`. 
I know that  I can get the  "b+c" string and apply a manual parsing based on the operator, but Im wondering if there is a more automated way using JDT

Thanks!

Comment: I would post this question on the JDT forum at eclipse.org. The JDT committers are there and will answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you are looking for 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName' nodes which have an 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IVariableBinding'. You should create an 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor' and override 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor.visit(SimpleName)'. Using the ASTVisitor you should then analyse the right hand side expression of a variable declaration.

You may find the 'How to find an AST Node' section of [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html) useful. You may also find the [AST View plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) useful.